# Dimension of sum and intersection of vector spaces (Strang's Linera Algebra question 43, section 3.4)

Tags: linear-algebra

The solution of the following problem is too abstract for me to understand so can anyone give me a better explanation?

This problem comes from the fifth edition of Gilbert Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra* question 43, section 3.4. The following is the description of the problem:

> Intersections and sums have $\dim(V) + \dim(W) = \dim(V\cap W) + \dim(V+W)$. Start with a basis $u_1,\dots,u_r$ for the intersection $V\cap W$. Extend with $v_1,\dots,v_s$ to a basis for V, and separately with $w_1,\dots, w_t$ to a basis for W. Prove that the $u$'s, $v$'s and $w$'s together are independent. The dimensions have $(r + s) + (r + t) = (r) + (r + s + t)$.

Comment: This is a fairly common theorem. Have you tried googling the proof?

Comment: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-dimension-of-a-sum-of-subspaces

Comment: I will if I understand this one since problem 44 which is the next problem of this one is about the proof of this theorem.

Comment: I see why thanks so much for the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different argument which starts from the bases $\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\}$ for $V$ and $\{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ for $W$.

Putting them together, we get
$$\{v_1, \ldots, v_m, w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$$
and this sets certainly spans $V+W$. We wish to reduce it to a basis for $V+W$ by eliminating those $w_i$ which can be expressed as a linear combination of its predecessors.

Start with $w_1$. If you can express it as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ as $$w_1 = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i^{(1)}v_i$$
then discard it from the set. Otherwise keep it in the set. Then look at $w_2$. If you can express it as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ (if we discarded $w_1$) or $v_1, \ldots, v_m, w_1$ (if we kept $w_1$) as
$$w_2 = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i^{(2)}v_i + \beta_1w_1$$
then discard it. Otherwise keep it in the set. Moving on, try to express $w_3$ as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_m, w_1, w_2$ (the $w_1$ and $w_2$ are here if we kept them in the set, otherwise no) and so on.

Do this until you reach the end of the set. You discarded some $w_i$-s, denote them as $w_1', \ldots, w_r'$. The set which remains
$$\{v_1, \ldots, v_m, w_1'', \ldots, w_s''\}=\{v_1, \ldots, v_m, w_1, \ldots, w_n\} \setminus \{w_1', \ldots, w_r'\}, \quad r+s=n$$
is now linearly independent since no element can be expressed as a linear combination of its predecessors. Hence it is a basis for $V+W$.

Those discarded you wrote as
$$w_i' = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_iv_i}_{=u_i'} + \underbrace{\sum \beta_jw_j''}_{=g_i'}.$$

The set $\{u_1', \ldots, u_r'\}$ is then a basis for $V \cap W$. Indeed, it is contained in $V \cap W$ since
$$u_i' = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_iv_i \in V, \qquad u_i' = w_i' - g_i' \in W.$$

$\{u_1', \ldots, u_r'\}$ is also linearly independent. We have
$$\sum_{i=1}^r \gamma_iu_i' = \sum_{i=1}^r \gamma_iw_i' - \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^r \gamma_ig_i'}_{\in\operatorname{span}\{w_1'', \ldots, w_s''\}}$$
so since $\{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ is a basis we conclude $\gamma_1 = \cdots = \gamma_n= 0$.

$\{u_1', \ldots, u_r'\}$ also spans $V \cap W$. Namely, if $x \in V \cap W$, then clearly we can write $x = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_iv_i$ and also
$$x = \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j w_j = \sum_{j=1}^r \beta_j'w_j'+\sum_{j=1}^s \beta_j''w_j'' = \sum_{j=1}^r \beta_j'u_j'+\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^r \beta_j'g_j' + \sum_{j=1}^s \beta_j''w_j''}_{\text{linear combination of $w_j''$-s}}$$
and so since $\{v_1, ldots, v_m, w_1'', \ldots, w_s''\}$ is a basis, from

$$0 = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_iv_i - \sum_{j=1}^r \beta_j'u_j'}_{\text{linear combination of $v_i$-s}} -\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^r \beta_j'g_j' + \sum_{j=1}^s \beta_j''w_j''}_{\text{linear combination of $w_j''$-s}}$$
we get $\sum_{j=1}^r \beta_j'g_j' + \sum_{j=1}^s \beta_j''w_j'' = 0$ and hence $$x = \sum_{j=1}^r \beta_j'u_j'.$$

Therefore $\{u_1', \ldots, u_r'\}$ is indeed a basis for $V \cap W$ and hence
$$\dim (V \cap W) + \dim (V+W) = (r) + (m+s) = m + (r+s) = m+n = \dim V + \dim W.$$

Answer (score 0):

The question is basically the building block to prove the theorem of dimension of direct sum of vector subspaces. Break it down as follows

1. Consider the intersection of subspaces $V$, $W$. Is that a vector space? Try convincing yourself that it is using the basic definition of a vector space. Since it is a subspace, it should have a dimension and a basis. For now, we assume that set to be $u = \{u_1, u_2...u_r\}$
2. What does the question mean by *extend*? Since $V\cap W$ is a subspace of both $V$ and $W$, one could take it's basis, and add elements to it to form a new basis for either $V$ or $W$. You have to essentially show that there is a way of doing this extension such that  all the additional vectors you add to form each basis are also mutually independent - this will allow to claim that the full set is a basis for the sum of the spaces